# Django - DRF - dispatch method flow

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am working with DRF to build an API and I used a master class to do some validations to my class based views:

```
class MasterClass(APIView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **
        response = super(FaveoAPIView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # I call super because I need access to request data.
        # <some validations here>
        # Return a JsonResponse with an error message if validations fails

class MyView(MasteClass):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # At this point request is: <WSGIRequest: POST '/api/path/'>
        # some DB transaction
        # ...
```

Validations are failing, at least one, but the DB transaction is being executed, I actually get a response with an error message from `dispatch` method, but `post` method is executed before `dispatch`, I use breakpoints to view the flow, and this is going into the `post` method and then to `dispatch` method, like if they were separated threads.

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/):

> The as_view entry point creates an instance of your class and calls
>   its dispatch() method. dispatch looks at the request to determine
>   whether it is a GET, POST, etc, and relays the request to a matching
>   method if one is defined, or raises HttpResponseNotAllowed if not.

So I thought that if I return a response with an error in dispatch, post method shouldn't be executed, why is it being executed? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to use a validate method on your serializer?

Comment: @ejey I don't need to validate a field, I need to avoid `.post()`'s execution if the request does not pass my validations in `.dispatch()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide the dispatch method code it'll just be guesses.
My 2 cents is that you're calling MasterClass's super at some point which will call the APIView dispatch which will call your POST.

Comment: You're right, i call `response = super(FaveoAPIView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` in some point inside `.dispatch()` before returning the error response. I do this because Django's generic `View`'s request, is not the same request that `APIView`. Since I need the DRF's request I call `super`. Do you know another way?

Comment: I edited the question, I call super in dispatch, because I need access to POST data there, so I call super to get the response object with the data, because when I try: request.POST I get an empty QueryDict

Comment: Instead of calling super, you should copy the original dispatch method and add your own logic there (https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L442)